# Textures not Baking in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I am attempting to bake textures into a fairly large UV map with cycles for an object that is meant to be placed in a video game. However, when I attempt to bake the textures, only specific areas of the mesh are baked, while other areas are left blank.

Is there a reason to this, and is there a way to fix it?

I run windows 7 64 bit with Blender 2.72 64 bit

[image: Nodes]

The textures here that actually do bake are "belt_buckle" "buckle_latch" "belt" and pieces of "Pouch"

here is an example of one of the nodes that do bake.
[image: working]

### EDIT

This is the blend file with all textures and normal maps involved. The textures are messy because I wanted to get them outlined quick and dirty to get to the neater bake sooner.

---

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nht3ftwwnmiy14n/bow%20and%20quiver42testing.blend?dl=0

Comment: Is it possible you could upload the .blend?

Comment: I've just added the files via dropbox

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. I looked at the file but I can't get it to bake anything meaningful.. (even after trying to correct the texture paths as best I could) All the texture references are messed up, so that might be why. If you are still looking for an answer, is it possible you could upload a version the textures packed into the .blend, so it stays exactly as you have it? This can be done by pressing *File > External Data > Pack into .blend* before uploading.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusing files and broken paths, I forgot that blender does not automatically detect the textures that its using in its folder. Ive updated the link with a packed .blend file. I'm assuming I did this correctly, if you run into any problems please feel free to contact me. Thank you for your help! (there were three files that were missing, however they were not intended to be used)